# What is the method to send a transaction with data from solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, 0x, swaps

Sorry for the noob question, but Im trying to understand some definitions and clarify the limits between solidity, web3, etc. I have obtained a tx looking like the following from the 0x API:

```
b'{"price":"3.84656292","guaranteedPrice":"3.808097289","to":"0x61935cbdd02287b511119ddb11aeb42f1593b7ef","data":"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","value":"8330000000000000","gas":"360000","estimatedGas":"300000","gasPrice":"119000000000","protocolFee":"8330000000000000","minimumProtocolFee":"8330000000000000","buyTokenAddress":"0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef","sellTokenAddress":"0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f","buyAmount":"3846562920","sellAmount":"1000000000","estimatedGasTokenRefund":"0","sources":[{"name":"0x","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Uniswap","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Uniswap_V2","proportion":"1"},{"name":"Eth2Dai","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Kyber","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Curve","proportion":"0"},{"name":"LiquidityProvider","proportion":"0"},{"name":"MultiBridge","proportion":"0"},{"name":"Balancer","proportion":"0"}],"orders":[{"chainId":1,"exchangeAddress":"0x61935cbdd02287b511119ddb11aeb42f1593b7ef","makerAddress":"0xc47b7094f378e54347e281aab170e8cca69d880a","takerAddress":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","feeRecipientAddress":"0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000011","senderAddress":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","makerAssetAmount":"3808097290","takerAssetAmount":"1000000000","makerFee":"0","takerFee":"0","expirationTimeSeconds":"1597097200","salt":"73837535216962425370204159489181198221250814604235035358532084460493382848240","makerAssetData":"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","takerAssetData":"0xf47261b00000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f","makerFeeAssetData":"0x","takerFeeAssetData":"0x","signature":"0x04"}],"allowanceTarget":"0x95e6f48254609a6ee006f7d493c8e5fb97094cef"}'
```

Now, if I pass it as an argument to a smart contract, how can I send it? Should I use address.call ? Should I sign it before passing it to solidity?

Answer (score 0):

For filling a quote in a contract, see this guide in our docs, https://0x.org/docs/guides/use-0x-api-liquidity-in-your-smart-contracts#the-fill-function